# Collection view images are not showing but the Url works fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I am trying to get images from server and show it in collection view as I have given background colour red I get plain red colour cells bt I have an image view and a label both those are not showing!!

I am getting the image names from server self.iname is an array in which I have stored image names!!This url thing works as I have used this for profile picture in a before view controller.so what is wrong in my code why am I not getting image view???thanks in advance for suggestions!!and yes I have given my datasource and delegates and given all my outlet connections.
I am using storyboard!!

this Is my collection view block-

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{


[collectionView registerClass:[ColCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

ColCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

[[[cell contentView] subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

UIView * contents=[[UIView alloc]      initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];

[contents setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

[cell.contentView addSubview:contents];

if([self.iname count]!=0){

[cell setTag:indexPath.row];    // set tag to the indexPath.row so we can access it later

// add interactivity
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonTapped:)];

[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];

[cell addGestureRecognizer:tap];

NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.iname]; //objectAtIndex:indexPath];

NSLog(@"%@",fileName);

NSString *baseurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.kre8tives.com/barebon/upload/"];

NSDictionary *dict = self.iname[indexPath.row];

NSLog(@"%@", [self.iname objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]);

NSString *paths = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", baseurl, dict];

NSLog(@"@@@@%@",paths);

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:paths]] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"%@",response);

    cell.dimg.image=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
   // UIImage *imgage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

   // cell.dimg.image=imgage;
    cell.lbl.text=[self.iname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@",[self.iname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
}];
}
    //cell.dimg.image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
     if (cell.selected) {
       cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; // highlight selection
     }
     else
     {
         cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Default color
     }
    return cell;
}
```

this is my collectionviewcell file (colcell.h)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ColCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dimg;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lbl;

@end
```

this is my collectionviewcell file .m (colcell.m)

```
 #import "ColCell.h"

 @implementation ColCell

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    UITapGestureRecognizer * tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onButtonTapped:)];
    [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

-(void)onButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
 //the response to the gesture.
//mind that this is done in the cell. If you don't want things to happen from this cell.
//then you can still activate this the way you did in your question.

}
@end
```

and this is one of my response

```
2017-06-14 09:03:03.647 MenuBar[754:23050] <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60000023c5c0> { URL:   http://test.kre8tives.com/barebon/upload/impotedbeernew.png } { status code: 200, headers {
"Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
"Cache-Control" = "max-age=2592000";
"Content-Length" = 8261;
"Content-Type" = "image/png";
Date = "Tue, 13 Jun 2017 12:04:47 GMT";
Etag = "\"31e1206-2045-551704d9ee800\"";
Expires = "Thu, 13 Jul 2017 12:04:47 GMT";
"Last-Modified" = "Thu, 08 Jun 2017 10:27:44 GMT";
Server = "Apache Phusion_Passenger/4.0.10 mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.9";
Vary = "User-Agent";
} }
2017-06-14 09:03:03.647 MenuBar[754:23050] impotedbeernew.png
2017-06-14 09:03:03.648 MenuBar[754:23050] <NSHTTPURLResponse:   0x60000023e360> { URL:     http://test.kre8tives.com/barebon/upload/blendedwhiskyne.png } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Accept-Ranges" = bytes;
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=2592000";
    "Content-Length" = 17188;
    "Content-Type" = "image/png";
    Date = "Tue, 13 Jun 2017 12:04:47 GMT";
    Etag = "\"31e118d-4324-5517150204640\"";
    Expires = "Thu, 13 Jul 2017 12:04:47 GMT";
    "Last-Modified" = "Thu, 08 Jun 2017 11:40:01 GMT";
    Server = "Apache Phusion_Passenger/4.0.10 mod_bwlimited/1.4 mod_fcgid/2.3.9";
    Vary = "User-Agent";
 } }
```

Comment: If image is shown, this code is also wrong, you will see the wrong image in cell, (because the cell-reuse system of `UICollectionView`).  `SDWebImage` can help you [https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
`[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:imageUrl]`

Comment: I have almost completed this n and I tried to add this lib but it didn't work well so I used my method itself!!@DungTran

Comment: i think its a bit wrong on how you register your `colcell`. registration should happen on the init of the collectionview not when it is already getting called

Comment: @Joshua what do u suggest I should do??

Comment: Try this:
**1**. call this on viewDidLoad `[collectionView registerClass:[ColCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];` 
 And then try **2**. `[cell.contentView addSubview:contents];` => `[cell addSubview:contents];` because collectionview cell contentview is nil

Comment: cell is not recognised in view did load !!giving me error@DungTran

Comment: @DungTran I get only red backgrounded cells but no image view still after doing your changes.

Comment: Change this also: `UIView * contents=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];` to `UIView * contents=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];`

Comment: yes did that and the same result. :(@DungTran

Comment: @DungTran jus checking where should the datasource and delegates should be given??

Comment: What happens if you remove this code line: `[collectionView registerClass:[ColCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];`?
If it crashes, did you register cell identifier like this? [https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBzIp.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBzIp.png).

Comment: no it didn't crash

Comment: yes I did that@DungTran

Comment: @DungTran many were saying no need to register if u use storyboard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146593/discussion-between-dung-tran-and-akshay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, remove these code will work for @Akshay.

```
[[[cell contentView] subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
UIView * contents=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];
[contents setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:contents];
```

Because they are unused codes and the first code line removes label `lbl` and imageView `dimg`, so they aren't displayed.